# Broken selection

Tags: selection-tools

Blender was normal but it suddenly broke. I'm not able to select using either box select or circle select (lasso is working just fine). The bug only shows up on object mode and the selection tool drop-down menu is acting weird as well. I've tried reinstalling the current version and changing it to more recent and older ones but it didn't work. BTW, it showed up when I closed my first 2.80 project. The tool has been broken ever since.

Comment: If there is something that worked and it doesn't work in newer version, post a bug report (just ensure it is not reported already, so search for similar first). Open Blender go to "Help" in top row menu and select "Report Bug". Also try open new file and go to "File" menu > Defaults > Load Factory to check if issue persist. Also try to check hardware specification, there can be a issue with unsupported graphic card.

Comment: Blender's user-interface is traditionally coded by a large herd of developmentally-challenged chinchillas. Such problems are to be expected.